# Detect if running in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

Are there any **widely accepted** methods for an *.exe to detect if it's running as part of an ADO pipeline?
The script will be running both as part of a pipeline and on workstations and should be able to determine with very high confidence where it is running, if possible.

Eg. any pre-defined variables that are meant for this (could not find) or some other pre-defined value that can be inspected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a whole number of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), most of which you could use, I would say. However, there is one which sounds like what you are looking for:

**TF_BUILD**

> Set to True if the script is being run by a build task.
>
> This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.

Comment: Last in the list. That's my bad. I thought I was thorough.

This is perfect, thanks.